# Falla al ejecutar aplicación VSTO con VB .NET cuando el usuario es NO administrador

Tags: excel, vb, instalacion

Gracias por leerlo y por cualquier ayuda, se desarrollo una aplicación en vsto + vb .net, hasta hay todo iba bien, se genero el instalador, y seguíamos bien, se probo el instalador en un equipo "limpio" y vamos bien, al notar que la prueba se estaba realizando con un usuario Administrador cambiamos  a un usuario autenticado, y esta no funciono, el Excel abre pero la aplicación no funciona. Muestra el siguiente error.:
"No se realizo la descarga de file:///C:Instalador........../Indices.dll.manifest correctamente"

Se modificaron los permisos de la carpeta a control total para el usuario de prueba pero siguió presentando el error, alguna idea?, una cosa mas, al instalarlo el instalador indica que la instalación termino correctamente.

Comment: Por seguridad, la creación automática de carpetas en el disco C: está bloqueado para usuarios no-administradores. Te sugiero utilizar la carpeta de "AppData" para bajar archivos. También te recomiendo ver estas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Ya lo intente y no funciono, le pregunte a Microsoft, en cuanto sepa algo lo comento